# CSS: Gmail stripping negative text-inline style

Tags: html, css, gmail

So, I've been trying to write a python script to automate some emails, and decided to format it in HTML. As a part of this, I would like to have some hanging indents in my email, and so I sued the following inline style:

```
<p style="margin-left:10px;text-indent:-10px">...</p>
```

This works beautifully on my Outlook web server but when I forward it to Gmail, I lose the text-indent property:

```
<p style="margin-left:10px">...</p>
```

After some playing around, I think it has to do with the negative indent value (positive works fine). Anyone know why this may be happening, or a potential workaround?